# Solar panel brackets not waterproofed correctly?

Tags: roof, waterproofing, solar-panels

We are having solar panels installed. They just squirt some glue or caulking under the mounting bracket and bolted it to the roof. In the YouTube videos the installers always cover them with flashing that inserts under the higher-up shingle.
Do you think this could stay waterproof? Or this a recipe for eventual leaks?
We live in Los Angeles, so there's no snow risk, but we have been getting a lot of rain lately.
[image: Picture of solar panel mounting bracket]
[image: Overview of solar panels]
[image: Another overview of solar panels]

Comment: If the bracket is secured with a lag bolt that enters the bracing/rafters, you'll have a secure mount. If sufficient sealant was applied, it's unlikely to leak. Our panels were installed with a spacer block that was swaged to a large sheet of aluminum, perhaps 12" square, one half of which slipped under the uphill shingle. The entire sheet was plastered with sealant. Somewhat overkill, but it does fit the belt and suspenders model.

Comment: Sufficient sealant applied is the key.  It is the top edge that matters most, if it sealed.

Comment: Plenty of TV aerials have been installed just like this over the last hundred years. Have a look in your attic after a rain and see what's what.

Comment: @isherwood Ha! You make a good point are the TV aerials. I remember my parents had one that was gradually cutting a circular opening through the shingles everytime the wind blew and spun it around like a weathervane.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Thanks for the thoughts on that. I was thinking that most of the rain will be blocked and diverted downroof by the panels themselves, so it's only the small bit of rain that lands on the bit of higher roof, so it won't be a ton of rain relatively speaking.

Comment: @crip659 That is definitely true. I couldn't really get a good look at them on their tops unfortunately. Now they are covered by the panels so I probably will never see!

Comment: What does the contract say about roof leaks from/after the install?

Comment: @crip659 Pretty vague about what they DO cover:  "Contractor is not responsible for roof leaks not directly caused by its work installing the System, nor any damage to personal property resulting from any roof leaks. Customer acknowledges the limitations of patching plaster and stucco, matching paint, matching texture and/or matching any finished product. Contractor will make reasonable efforts to match all existing conditions (i.e. textures and colors), however exact duplication is not promised nor guaranteed."

Comment: "reasonable effort" there's some lovely lawyer weasel wording! "Yeah, this is the best we could get from Lowe's pre-mixed return counter, that's the best effort we could make." Go ahead, prove me wrong...

Comment: @FreeMan So true! Agree with you 100%.